# Как исправить ошибку <map object at 0x000001BF2B669FA0>?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda

Умножьте все элементы списка `[12, 24, 36, 48, 109, 187]`  на `17`. 
Нужно перебрать все элементы при помощи цикла и умножить их.

Решить эту задачу используя `lambda-функцию` для умножения числа и применить ее при помощи функции `map()` ко всему списку.

Как исправить эту ошибку ?

> <map object at 0x0000000002997A20>

---

**main.py**:

```
mas = [12, 24, 36, 48, 109, 187] 
 
for i in range(len(mas)):
    bobo = (lambda a, b: a * b)(mas[i], 17)

b = map(bobo, mas)
print(b)
```

Comment: Это не ошибка, это строковое представление функции map. Напишите, например `print(list(b))`

Comment: теперь выдает  'int' object is not callable.. AAAAAA

Comment: код и текст ошибки в вопросе должны быть текстом.

Comment: Число 3179 в переменной bobo, которое вы передаете в map(), не функция. Поэтому и `'int' object is not callable`

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
mas = [12, 24, 36, 48, 109, 187] 

bobo = (lambda a: a * 17)
b = map(bobo, mas)

print(f'\n{list(b)}\n')
```